# How do I authenticate GKE to my third-party private docker registry?

Tags: kubernetes, docker-registry, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'd like to deploy pods into my GKE Kubernetes cluster that use images from a private, third-party Docker registry (*not* GCP's private Docker registry).

How do I provide my GKE Kubernetes cluster with credentials to that private repository so that the images can be pulled when required?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a secret that holds the credentials needed to download images from the private registry. [This process is explained on Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/), but it looks like

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regsecret --docker-server=<your-registry-server> --docker-username=<your-name> --docker-password=<your-pword> --docker-email=<your-email>
```

Then, once your secret has been created, you need to specify that you want to use this secret to pull images from the registry when creating the pod's containers with the `imagePullSecrets` key containing the name of the secret created above, like

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: private-reg
spec:
  containers:
  - name: private-reg-container
    image: <your-private-image>
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regsecret
```

Comment: I knew about secrets, but have never noticed `imagePullSecrets`.  Thanks!